# ¿Cómo comunicar html del webextension con background.js en Firefox?

Tags: javascript, extensión-google-chrome, firefox-webextensions

Estoy desarrollando un extension para chrome y firefox webextension, y necesito comunicar una pagina html digamos `popup.html` con el script `backgound.js`.

En chrome todo funciona bien haciendo uso de la API de Mensajes, sin embargo en firefox la pagina `popup.html` no reconoce dicho API y tampoco encuentro manera alguna de injectarle un `contentScript`.

Mi ultimo intento es el codigo siguiente:

**manifest.json**

```
    {

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "testApp",
  "description": "foo",
  "version": "1.0",      
  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/message-48.png"
  },

  "applications": {
    "gecko": {
      "id": "foo@bar.org",
      "strict_min_version": "45.0"
    }
  },

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "popup.html",
    "popup.js"
  ],

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://localhost/*"],
      "js": ["content-script.js"]
    }
  ],

  "permissions": [
     "tabs"
  ]

}
```

**backgroud.js**

```
var hash;

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {   
        if (request.operation === "send"){
            receive(request.hash);
        }       
        return true;
    }
);

function receive(value) {
    hash = value;
    var popupId;
    var signURL = chrome.extension.getURL("pupup.html");
    chrome.windows.create(
        {url: signURL},
        function (newWindow) {
            popupId = newWindow.id;    
        }
    );
    var arrayWindow = chrome.extension.getViews({"windowId":popupId});
    arrayWindow[0].document.getElementById('hash').value=hash;
}
```

**content-script.js**

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
  if (event.source == window &&
      event.data.direction &&
      event.data.direction == "from-page-script") {
    console.log("content script sending message: "+ "'" +event.data.message+"'");
    var jsonValue = JSON.parse(event.data.message);
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(jsonValue);
  }
});
```

**pupup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>pupup</title>
  </head>
  <body>   
    <label for="hash"> Hash recibido: </label><input type="input" id="hash"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

**local.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">   
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Enviando mensaje a popup.html</p>

    <input id="from-page-script" type="button" value="Enviando Valor">
    <script src="./js/messaging.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**messaging.js**

```
var messenger = document.getElementById("from-page-script");

messenger.addEventListener("click", messageContentScript);

function messageContentScript() {
  window.postMessage({
    direction: "from-page-script",
    message: '{"operation":"send","hash":"xdhHNrpFF0fdXw650X4QTzaX70c="}'
  }, "*");
}
```

Sin embargo *chrome.extension.getViews* retorna vacio.

¿Alguna idea de como puedo hacer lo que necesito?

Comment: Todavía no manejo el tema de los popup, pero hace unos días me respondieron una pregunta similar que hice. [Crear una extensión de Chrome inyectando código Javascript](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/23095), espero que te sirva.

Comment: En el título se menciona Firexfox pero al final se menciona Chrome, Si la pregunta es sobre ambos, me parece que es demasiado amplia, si sólo se trata sobre uno, entonces me parece que no está clara.

Answer (score 1):

para el contentScript:

```
"permissions": [
  "tabs",
  "nativeMessaging",
  "webRequest",
  "`<all_urls>`"
],
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["`<all_urls>`"],
       "js": ["contentScript.js"]

    }
]
```

en el contentScript añadimos el listener:

```
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
   function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  // tu codigo
  }
});
```

Y para las llamadas al background:

```
browser.runtime.sendMessage(mensaje);
```

Y los mensajes desde background hacia content:

```
browser.tabs.sendMessage(data.tabId,mensaje);
```

y los listener en backgroud son iguales que los de contentscript.

Espero que te ayude